# Raspberry Pi 3 Windows IoT Core

Tags: windows-iot, pi-3

Windows IoT dashboard only has an option "Raspberry Pi 2". What if I have RPi 3? Can I use RPi 2 image on Raspberry Pi 3?

Answer (score 1):

I tried installing the existing RPi2 version on my RPi 3B+ and it didn't boot up!
I was hoping it would boot up without the Bluetooth and WiFi working, but nothing happened. There are beta versions available for RPi 3B+ if you are a member of the IoT core insider programme which apparently was full last time I checked.

Answer (score 0):

You need a new build for the Pi 3.  It is still a preview build and doesn't support the Wi-Fi or BT but it does work.  You can find more at this link which includes a link to the preview build: [Windows 10 IoT Core support for Raspberry Pi 3](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/02/29/windows-10-iot-core-support-for-raspberry-pi-3/).